# Running Qt 4.7 application in Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid Lynx

Tags: qt, ubuntu, qt4, ubuntu-10.04

I am working on a cross-platform application, and am using the latest Qt libraries, version 4.7. The problem is, one of the users tried to run it on Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid Lynx, and it crashed with `undefined symbol: _ZN9QListData11detach_growEPii`. Ubuntu 10.04 has Qt4.6.3 and it seems to be the problem.

However, it seems Ubuntu 10.04 doesn't support 4.7- only Ubuntu 10.10 does, and the user does not want to upgrade his linux distribution as his is Long Term Support. What are my options in this case? The user could potentially download the 4.7 framework and compile that on his PC, but that would mean every ubuntu 10.04 user would have to do this. Alternatively, I could make extra builds using Qt 4.6, but I can't find these older libraries.

Any suggestions? Are there any compile flags that would make it compatible with 4.6? Could this be a bug?

Thanks!

EDIT: I ended up sending him my Qt .so files, and it worked. However, everyone's answer here was correct and appropriate- I wish I could accept them all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from linking statically against Qt, you can also simply distribute your Qt DLLs/so files along with your executable. The instruction on Qt deployment page is clear http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/deployment-x11.html

Comment: Not only Qt .so files, but also platform/compiler specific libraries (for example, libc.so etc) - this is not convenience.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, and it worked! It might not apply for all cases like Johnny said, but for this case I was lucky that all other dependencies matched on our machines.

Comment: If you have trouble with ./configure on Ubuntu 10.04 make sure you have the 'libxext-dev' pkg installed first.  Then it should be easy sailing...

Answer (score 5):

See the last post
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1552263

You need to add this to your repository sources:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/backports/ubuntu lucid main
```

Comment: By adding a new source repo containing newer libs, a small apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade will update Qt to the newer version. (Like I mentionned, you need to scroll down to the latest answer in the post I linked to) But as chx pointed out, this is probably more a superuser question ..

Comment: The user didn't manage to get the backport, as it asked for "signed stuff" only. I ended up sending him my .so files. Thanks!

Comment: This command adds the repository correctly with key for "signed stuff":


`sudo apt-add-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports`

Answer (score 1):

To the contrary, he needs QT 4.6.3. I presume he is on 10.10 but needs the Qt from 10.04. This requires

```
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid main restricted universe multiverse
```

now you can

```
sudo apt-get build-dep libqt4-core libqt4-dev
sudo apt-get -b source -t lucid libqt4-core libqt4-dev
```

build the lucid version (add more qt packages as needed).

Ps. you are on the wrong site, this is more like unix.* or superuser.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but you got everything exactly backwards. :P I have Qt 4.7, he has Ubuntu 10.04 with Qt 4.6.3. If one searches for the error, here's one of the results which suggests getting Qt 4.7 http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/applications/446948-symbol-lookup-errors-after-updating-libkdecore4.html

Comment: The user could potentially download the 4.7 framework and compile that on his PC, but that would mean every ubuntu 10.04 user would have to do this. Alternatively, I could make extra builds using Qt 4.6, but I can't find these older libraries.<= I answered this question, how to find 4.6.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood you. I assumed by "he" you were referring to the user, not me. Thing is i'm not on Ubuntu, i'm on CentOS (server at work) which is another story.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can build your app statically against Qt libraries. See http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/deployment-x11.html#static-linking
So you'll be able to distribute your app anywhere (Ubuntu 9.*/10.*) without installing Qt SDK on target machines.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am using Qt under the LGPL license, so I cannot statically link against Qt.